# Strech an image vertically to fill a div

Tags: css

Playing around with this mostly for fun. NOT a professional. But im trying to get an image to fill a div vertically by hopefully streching the entire height of the div. But not familar enough with this to figure it out.

Here is the CSS

```
div#rightarch {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
float: right;
margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}
```

here is the html

```
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3">
<div id="rightarch">
<img src="images/right-arches.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be awesome...

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to give the image a size. All you're doing is give the div a size, which won't influence the img.

Comment: ahhh...thanks...i felt kind of dumb as soon as i read that...i will try to work on that now...thanks...